# Delphi "remembers" old DCU dependency

Tags: delphi

I'm moving development of an application from one machine (same version of Delphi).  The original version of the application used a TMoneyEdit component from the TMS pack.  While moving the project I'd like to remove the dependency on that product.  So, in the source, I removed the TMoneyEdit component and replaced it with one of my own.  I also removed the MoneyEdit reference from the unit's USING clause.

However, Delphi still will not compile my application, giving the error File not found MoneyEdit.DCU.

If I search all files in the project for "moneyedit" I find nothing.  I've even searched across my hard disk, and the only references to moneyedit are in the original TMS component files (and I have no references to TMS in my project, either).

Obviously, there's still a dependency stored somewhere.  Can anyone tell me where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When moving from one computer to another did you take any DCU's from your current project with you? I may be that one of your projects DCU's are out dated and sill using the old code base. If that is the case doing a full clean and build should solve it.

Comment: Doing a full rebuild did the trick.  I don't _think_ there was any reference outside of the single file I modified, but perhaps that wasn't being recompiled.

Comment: Aha.  I'm moving to a new computer, and the Windows date setting was one day off, making my edited .pas file appear older than the .dcu file I copied.

Comment: Personally I think that the delphi compiler should force a full rebuild and maybe even a clean, whenever you remove any unit from the project.   There are times when a partial build never makes sense, and this is one of them.